# Scrapy Stripping Comma

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, strip

```
import scrapy
import pandas as pd
from ..items import HomedepotpricespiderItem
from scrapy.http import Request


class HomedepotspiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'homeDepotSpider'
    allowed_domains = ['homedepot.com']

    
    start_urls = ['https://www.homedepot.com/pep/304660691']#.format(omsID = omsID)
        #for omsID in omsList]

    def parse(self, response):

    #call home depot function
        for item in self.parseHomeDepot(response):
            yield item

        pass

    def parseHomeDepot(self, response):

        #get top level item
        items = response.css('#zone-a-product')
        for product in items:
            item = HomedepotpricespiderItem()

    #get SKU
            productSKU = product.css('.product-info-bar__detail:nth-child(2)::text').getall()

    #get rid of all the stuff i dont need
            #productSKU = [x.strip(' ') for x in productSKU] #whiteSpace
            #productSKU = [x.strip(',') for x in productSKU] 
            #productSKU = [x.strip('\n') for x in productSKU]
            #productSKU = [x.strip('\t') for x in productSKU]
            #productSKU = [x.strip(' Model# ') for x in productSKU] #gets rid of the model name
```

So my selectors are fine and they get the correct fields.

When running with the strip lines commented out I get '**Model #,RA30**'

then when I run my program with the strip commands not commented out I get **,RA30**

Im running my program using this command in terminal: `scrapy crawl homeDepotSpider -t csv -o - > "/Users/userName/Desktop/homeDepotv2Helpers/homeDepotTest.csv"`

and the output I have above is copied directly from the CSV

Edit*

I've also tried this

```
productSKU = [x.replace(' ,', '') for x in productSKU]
```

and that didn't work. Also this is the direct output from terminal `{'productSKU': ['', 'RA30']}`

Comment: So, your problem is that the comma doesn't get stripped?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your selector gives you a list of two elements: `['Model #', 'RA30']`.

To get only the SKU, simply use indexing:

```py
productSKU = product.css('.product-info-bar__detail:nth-child(2)::text').getall()[1]
```

If there's a chance that a product won't have an SKU, make sure to handle exceptions correctly.

Comment: thanks you! that solution was the way to go and it helped out with other selectors

Answer (score 2):

The [strip](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_strip.asp) function will only remove signs or substrings at the beginning or end of a string. If you want to remove a character no matter where in the string, use the [replace](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_replace.asp) function.
However, if you only want to remove the comma in the beginning or at the end of your string, you should repeat your line `productSKU = [x.strip(',') for x in productSKU]` once more after `roductSKU = [x.strip(' Model# ') for x in productSKU]`

Comment: so is it generally better to to use replace instead of strip when trying to clean up strings?

Comment: i tried productSKU = [x.replace(' ,', '') for x in productSKU]  and your recommendation and neither worked :(

Comment: In your replace statement there is a white space before the comma. Please try it like this: `productSKU = [x.replace(' ,', '') for x in productSKU] `. You can also try to add this strip call after the *Model#* strip: `productSKU = [x.strip(' ,') for x in productSKU]`

Comment: Also, since I can't access the link in your start_urls list, I think that the solution provided by stranac might be the right one.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you want to use XPath + regex?

```
product_model = response.xpath('//h2[@class="product-info-bar__detail"][contains(., "Model #")]/text()').re_first(r'#(.+)')
```